# Create texture after WIC Loading in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, textures

I am pretty new to DirectX, and have trouble understanding some of the texture loading. I basically want to load a texture from a JPG file using D3D. Since the `createTextureFromFile` and `createTextureFromMemory` are deprecated, I tried the WIC Loader, but can't figure out how to use it.

Earlier, this was part of the code I had:

```
        ID3D11DeviceContext* ctx = NULL;
        g_D3D11Device->GetImmediateContext(&ctx);

        // update native texture from code
        if (unity_TexturePointer)
        {
            ID3D11Texture2D* d3dtex = (ID3D11Texture2D*)unity_TexturePointer;
            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
            d3dtex->GetDesc(&desc);

            // filled data is an unsigned char* and has the data

            ctx->UpdateSubresource(d3dtex, 0, NULL, filledData, (width * 4), 0);
            delete[] filledData;
        }
        ctx->Release();
```

Now, coming to WIC loading, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960986/directx11-createwictexturefrommemory-using-png) post. I now have:

```
        ID3D11DeviceContext* ctx = NULL;
        g_D3D11Device->GetImmediateContext(&ctx);

        // update native texture from code
        if (unity_TexturePointer)
        {
            ID3D11Texture2D* d3dtex = (ID3D11Texture2D*)unity_TexturePointer;
            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
            d3dtex->GetDesc(&desc);

            ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> srv;

            std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char> file("bridge.jpg", std::ios::binary);

            if (file.is_open())
            {
                file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
                int length = file.tellg();
                file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

                unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[length];
                file.read(&buffer[0], length);
                file.close();

                HRESULT hr;
                hr = CreateWICTextureFromMemory(g_D3D11Device, ctx, &buffer[0], (size_t)length, nullptr, &srv, NULL);

                // What goes here??
            }
        }
        ctx->Release();
```

I am totally confused what now. I somehow want that texture that is loaded to reach my `d3dtex` Texture2D pointer.

I am referring to the [header file](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/WICTextureLoader/WICTextureLoader.h) and I see that we can pass the Texture pointer too, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

`hr = CreateWICTextureFromMemory(g_D3D11Device, ctx, &buffer[0], (size_t)length, &d3dtex, nullptr, NULL);`

It throws the error, there is no instance of overloaded function. I wanted to do this so directly my Texture pointer would be updated, since I am not quite sure how to work with the `ShaderResourceView`.

Similar problems for the `CreateWICTextureFromFile` methods.

Basically, I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong, and would appreciate any help or examples for the same, as the example in the [Microsoft documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) doesn't really help me.

Thanks!

Comment: If your question has been answered satisfactorily, it would be nice for you to mark the answer as "accepted", and upvote if you found it particularly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: And if there';s still a problem with the answer, please do say so, because that's the only way to get them improved.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is that `CreateWICTextureFromMemory` creates an `ID3D11Resource`, and `d3dtex` is an `ID3D11Texture2D`. COM class and interface hierarchies can't always be trivially interconverted in the same way that instances of C++ classes can.

Look at the answers to this question here for how to use `QueryInterface` or `GetResource` to convert between `ID3D11Resource` and `ID3D11Texture2D`.

[Down Casting ID3D11Texture2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493929/down-casting-id3d11texture2d)

Comment: Downvoting without comment is useless and helps no-one. Furthermore, systematically downvoting the questions and answers of a user is the sort of thing that triggers automatic anti-abuse systems and moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks @Rook, this was helpful. I will try it out. I am relatively new to SO, and see that my question got downvoted. Any idea on how I could have improved my question to avoid that in the future? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried `hr = CreateWICTextureFromMemory(g_D3D11Device, ctx, &buffer[0], (size_t)length, nullptr, &srv, NULL);

hr = ctx->QueryInterface(IID_ID3D11Texture2D, (void **)&d3dtex);` and my Unity just got unresponsive. When I tried `hr = CreateWICTextureFromMemory(g_D3D11Device, ctx, &buffer[0], (size_t)length, nullptr, &srv, NULL);

ctx->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &srv);`, the plugin ran but no texture. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, `hr = CreateWICTextureFromMemory(g_D3D11Device, ctx, &buffer[0], (size_t)length, nullptr, &srv, NULL)` makes no mention of the resource you're writing the texture to. Do your `QueryInterface` first to get a suitable resource, then pass the resource into `CreateWICTextureFromMemory`.